# Does interface builder support multiple image resolutions for different screen sizes?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

The form factor button is great for testing the different iphone screen sizes, as is the assitant editor preview for older iOS version layouts.
Ofcourse if there is a background image that covers most of the screen then we need to creating tweaked images to fit the available space in each screen configuration.
Coding for it is the obvious way but working intuitively in interface builder becomes broken.
Does IB support this somehow I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way of doing it is you can just load different XiBs depending on the screen size. Create two XiBs - VC1 and VC2.

You can then do this:

```
if([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 1136) {
    MyViewController *vc = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"VC1"];
    // push vc in Navigation Controller
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds].size.height == 960) {
     MyViewController *vc = [[MYViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"VC2"];
    // push vc in Navigation Controller
}
```

Hope that helped. I've used this method before and it worked fine. Also, apologies if there are any typos in the code. Didn't type it in Xcode.

Comment: Yes I considered that but maintaining 2 versions of the storyboard seems like uneccesary work when the form factor controls cover everything except multiple images. Hopefully it's something they will add in future. I see now the benefits of creating everything in code and abandoning IB all together.

Comment: Yes thats what I prefer doing actually. Alternately you can use Auto Layout as well if you want to maintain spaces between the controls on your view.

Comment: Also appears to be a bug in the ios6 preview. I'm generally finding the need to add a 30-50px gap between objects and the status bar for them to align properly when running the app.

Comment: Oh I haven't used that. Xcode 5 final has released though. So maybe they've fixed they bug there.

Comment: Nope same in Xcode 5. Strangely, if I change any properties of the navigation bar like tint, the objects will align without the gap.